# Memory consumption in PyArrow iter_batches

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow

Let's suppose I have n parquet files that represent the columns of my final parquet file. The columns have 5 milion rows and I want to read my entire file in batches and each batch is given by the concatenation of the batches of all columns as follows

```
def read_arrow_col_batch(path_to_column: str, column: str, batch_size: int = 10_000):
    """
    Read a column from parquet column and return a pyarrow.Table table containing it.

    :param batch_size: size of the batch
    :param path_to_column: path to parquet that contains the column
    :param column: Column Name.
    """

    parquet_file = ParquetFile(path_to_column)
    for batch in parquet_file.iter_batches(columns=[column], batch_size=batch_size):
        yield batch
    
def read_arrow_cols_batch(paths_to_columns: List[str], columns: List[str], batch_size: int = 10_000):
    """
    Read all columns batches
    :param batch_size: size of the batch
    :param paths_to_columns: paths to parquet files that contains the columns
    :param columns: Column Names.
    """

    pqs_batches = [read_arrow_col_batch(path_to_column=p, column=c) for c, p in zip(columns, paths_to_columns)]
    for idx, zipped_batches in enumerate(zip(*pqs_batches)):
        batches = [z[0] for z in zipped_batches]
        t = pa.Table.from_arrays(batches, names=columns)
        yield t
```

why does this consume more memory than if I apply the `iter_batches` function to the `ParquetFile` object of the entire parquet file? Am I missing something? There exists a method to combine all parquet files in one object without allocating memory?

Comment: Why extracting only `z[0]` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest because this gives me the ```RecordBatch``` object for each column

Comment: *if I apply the iter_batches function to the ParquetFile object of the entire parquet file* - that's still one entire file, but you're processing plenty of such files

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes because I have n ```ParquetFile``` objects which represent the columns of the entire parquet file. I have this constraint unfortunately.

Comment: Do all those files have the same schema?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest the type of the columns could be different and each file contains only one column

Comment: _why does this consume more memory than if I apply the iter_batches function to the ParquetFile object of the entire parquet file? Am I missing something?_ - could you post the code of what you are comparing to? _There exists a method to combine all parquet files in one object without allocating memory?_ - There is a way to do this for concatenating table vertically/row wise, but it looks like you are doing it by column.

Comment: @0x26res for the first point it's just the ```iter_batches``` function applied to the ```ParquetFile``` object of the entire parquet file (I don't have the entire file in my case but I have tested it using a big file and splitting it to columns to compare the two approaches)